# How to repeat the song untill not stop playing off

Tags: android

How to repeat the song in android.the code is as follows. I want to repeat current song until I stop.

```
              loop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                if(isRepeat){
                    isRepeat = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Repeat is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               //     togglePlay(Songs.current_track);
                    loop.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                }else{
                    // make repeat to true
                    isRepeat = true;

                    //  togglePlay(Songs.current_track);


                    // make shuffle to false
                //    isShuffle = false;
                    loop.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    shuffle.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                }
            }
        });
```

[Here is the complete code](http://pastie.org/9107136)

Comment: how do you play your song?Do you use MediaPlayer?

Comment: mike vol check the link